# Listing all folders in my directory visual basic

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I am trying to list all my folders from a drive in a directory onto an excel spreadsheet with a touch of a button. I made the button and assigned this macro... why won't it compile? The *** **** shows what they debugged. Said object folder was not an object. Please help!

```
Sub ListAllFile()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = Worksheets.Add

 'Get the folder object associated with the directory

***Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:hello\EMILY")***
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = objFolder.Name

 'Loop through the Files collection
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: `c:hello` is a relative path, on the C: drive. whatever director was last `cd`'d to on C: drive will be used as the "base" for that path. Maybe you meant `c:\hello`? (note the backslash).

Comment: That is not VB.NET code, and VB.NET doesnt do macros. I suspect you meant to use the excel-vba tag

Comment: @MarcB I tried that. Still nothing.

Comment: @Plutonix what is the code?

Comment: Is the error what you wrote?  Or is the error "object required".  If the latter, In your error line, your are using `fso` as an object, but you never set `fso` to anything.  You would have found this out had you set the option in VBA to require variable declaration, which puts `Option Explicit` at the beginning.  Try that and you will see what I mean.  That error message is because you never declare `fso` as an object.

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to get the folder names, unless you actually want files. It was modified from your original code. I commented out the excel/worksheet logic.

Part of the problem was fso.GetFolder was not an object which was declared and set. If you want still want files, you can change objFolder.Subfolders to .Files

```
Sub ListAllFile()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Set ws = Worksheets.Add

 'Get the folder object associated with the directory

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\users")
'ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = objFolder.Name

'Loop through the Files collection
For Each objFile In objFolder.subfolders
 MsgBox objFile.Name ' to test output
'ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  Here is one way.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FileListingAllFolder()

Dim pPath As String
Dim FlNm As Variant
Dim ListFNm As New Collection ' create a collection of filenames

Dim OWb As Workbook
Dim ShtCnt As Integer
Dim Sht As Integer

Dim MWb As Workbook
Dim MWs As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

' Open folder selection
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    pPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Create master workbook with single sheets
Set MWb = Workbooks.Add(1)
MWb.Sheets(1).Name = "Result"
Set MWs = MWb.Sheets("Result")
Cells(1, 1) = "No."
Cells(1, 2) = "Sheet Name"
Cells(1, 3) = "File Name"
Cells(1, 4) = "Link"
i = 2

' Filling a collection of filenames (search Excel files including subdirectories)
Call FlSrch(ListFNm, pPath, "*.xls", True)

' Print list to immediate debug window and as a message window
For Each FlNm In ListFNm ' cycle for list(collection) processing

    'Start Processing here
    Set OWb = Workbooks.Open(FlNm)
    ShtCnt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For Sht = 1 To ShtCnt
        MWs.Cells(i, 1) = i - 1
        MWs.Cells(i, 2) = Sheets(Sht).Name
        MWs.Cells(i, 3) = OWb.Name
        MWs.Cells(i, 4).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FlNm & """,""Click Here"")"
        i = i + 1
    Next Sht
    'End file processing file
    OWb.Close False
Next FlNm

' Print to immediate debug window and message if no file was found
If ListFNm.Count = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No file was found !"
    MsgBox "No file was found !"
    MWb.Close False
    End
End If

MWb.Activate
MWs.Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

End

NextCode:
MsgBox "You Click Cancel, and no folder selected!"

End Sub

Private Sub FlSrch(pFnd As Collection, pPath As String, pMask As String, pSbDir As Boolean)

Dim flDir As String
Dim CldItm As Variant
Dim sCldItm As New Collection

' Add backslash at the end of path if not present
pPath = Trim(pPath)
If Right(pPath, 1) <> "\" Then pPath = pPath & "\"

' Searching files accordant with mask
flDir = Dir(pPath & pMask)
    Do While flDir <> ""
        pFnd.Add pPath & flDir 'add file name to list(collection)
        flDir = Dir ' next file
    Loop

' Procedure exiting if searching in subdirectories isn't enabled
If Not pSbDir Then Exit Sub

' Searching for subdirectories in path
flDir = Dir(pPath & "*", vbDirectory)
    Do While flDir <> ""

        ' Add subdirectory to local list(collection) of subdirectories in path
        If flDir <> "." And flDir <> ".." Then If ((GetAttr(pPath & flDir) And _
        vbDirectory) = 16) Then sCldItm.Add pPath & flDir
        flDir = Dir 'next file
    Loop

' Subdirectories list(collection) processing
For Each CldItm In sCldItm
    Call FlSrch(pFnd, CStr(CldItm), pMask, pSbDir) ' Recursive procedure call
Next

End Sub
```

Also, check out the link below.

http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/download/

Save the file from the link named 'File Manager (Excel Workbook)'.  That is a very cool app!!